# Elliptic principal eigenfunction analysis for Langevin dynamics with a varying source term

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the Kolmogorov forward equation for a Langevin dynamic:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f = \Delta f + \Div(f\nabla V)\\
\\
\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(x) dx = 1,
\end{cases}$$
it's well-known that this system admits an invariant density function $\nu(x) = Ce^{-V(x)}$, which is exactly the solution to the equation $$\Delta \nu + \Div(\nu \nabla V) = 0.$$

Now if I add a source term in the evolution equation, and assume the source term is monotonic function of the original potential:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f = \Delta f + \Div(f\nabla V) + m(V) f,
$$
where $m: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonically decreasing.
This system is generally not a evolution of probabilistic density, or to say,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(x,t) dx \neq 0.
$$
BTW, we can still define a probabilistic density $p$ proportional to $f$: $p(x,t) = \frac{f(x,t)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(y,t) dy}$. It can be shown that the limit distribution $\lim_{t \to \infty}p(t,x) = \mu(x)$ is exactly the principal eigenfunction to the elliptic eigenvalue problem:
$$
\Delta \mu + \Div(\mu\nabla V) + m(V) \mu = \lambda \mu.
$$
Here raise a question: is $\mu$ sharper than $\nu$? Or to say, whether there exists a monotonically decreasing function $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\frac{\mu(x)}{\nu(x)} = \gamma(V(x))$ or not?

————————

Why to ask this question, let's take $\nu$ as the initial condition to the parabolic equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(x,t) dx \neq 0$$
and then will arrive at
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,0) = m(V) f(x,0)$$
take $t = \epsilon$,
$$f(x,\epsilon) \approx (1 + \epsilon m(V))\nu(x).$$
Thus I wonder if this property will preserve in a long time, as well as the limit situation.

Comment: TeX note: although harmless, `\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{\operatorname{div}}` is the same as `\DeclareMathOperator\Div{div}`; there's no need for an explicit `\operatorname`.

Comment: @LSpice thank you very much. This definitively simplifies my definitions.